# int(np.float128) cast precision loss

Tags: python

When I run:

```
import numpy as np
print(hex(int(np.float128(2**64-1))))
print(hex(int(np.float128(2**65-1))))
```

I get:

```
0xffffffffffffffff
0x20000000000000000
```

2**64-1 is correctly returned. However, 2**65-1 is not correctly returned. I should have [112 significant bits (mantissa)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format), so this shouldn't be a problem. But it is.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: floating point imprecision?

Comment: `np.float128(2**65-1) == np.float128(2**65)` is `True` when I test it, so the problem is not the `int` conversion, it's the `float128` conversion.

Comment: Basically, `np.float128` is not necessary a quadruple precision binary floating point number. See the linked duplicate candidate (which may just be a duplicate appropriate for closing).

Comment: ["In spite of the names, np.float96 and np.float128 provide only as much precision as np.longdouble, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and 64 bits in standard Windows builds."](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)